# Is there a better way to analyze refreshing a materialized view in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, materialized-views, explain, postgresql-performance

If I have a slow query, I can run explain analyze and I get a sensible output:

```
donapaz=> explain analyze select * from datapoints, gics_codes;
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..26628.48 rows=1655840 width=3050) (actual time=0.937..388.157 rows=1655840 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on datapoints  (cost=0.00..5913.20 rows=6320 width=2769) (actual time=0.904..3.106 rows=6320 loops=1)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.93 rows=262 width=281) (actual time=0.000..0.008 rows=262 loops=6320)
         ->  Seq Scan on gics_codes  (cost=0.00..16.62 rows=262 width=281) (actual time=0.021..0.106 rows=262 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.367 ms
 Execution Time: 425.623 ms
(6 rows)
```

So far, so good. I can create a materialized view from my query (and yes, the query is a bit meaningless - that's not the point)

```
donapaz=> create materialized view my_silly_view as select * from datapoints, gics_codes;
SELECT 1655840
donapaz=>
```

I can analyze queries against the view:

```
donapaz=> explain analyze select * from my_silly_view where company_id = 'bob';
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..408241.27 rows=1 width=2948) (actual time=394.916..395.597 rows=0 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on my_silly_view  (cost=0.00..407241.17 rows=1 width=2948) (actual time=387.455..387.456 rows=0 loops=3)
         Filter: ((company_id)::text = 'bob'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 551947
 Planning Time: 0.252 ms
 Execution Time: 395.676 ms
(8 rows)
```

Equally good. However, in order for the view to be useful I need to periodically (maybe quite frequently) refresh it. This can be quite slow. However, if I try and analyze why it's slow I get a pretty unhelpful error message:

```
donapaz=> explain analyze refresh materialized view my_silly_view;
                QUERY PLAN                 
-------------------------------------------
 Utility statements have no plan structure
(1 row)

donapaz=>
```

Now I can obviously analyze my view by simply taking the query for the view definition, copying and pasting it into another file and running that as a query, but it feels like there really should be a better way. Is there?

Comment: Refreshing a materialized view does not make use of parallel workers, while creating the MV does... so it might be faster to drop+recreate the MV.

Comment: On a side note, you can index the MV to make it more efficient

Answer (score 0):

For a real world query if you are executing `refresh materialized view concurrently the_view;` then the performance characteristics of `concurrently` can really slow down the refresh depending on what the `select` traffic against the view is like. This wasn't addressed in the question, but it is a factor to keep in mind.

You should be able to get an idea of what the actual performance of gathering the data to create the view is like based on your `explain`. The difference between that `explain` and the `refresh` is everything else. You can optimize for improving the result set execution performance by adjusting `work_mem` (e.g., `set local work_mem='256MB';` prior to executing the `refresh` - this `local` setting will only affect the very next command ran in that session). Then the characteristics of the view as it exists will come into effect - are many rows being updated, and if so, is fillfactor having a negative performance impact? Is the fillfactor of any indexes that may exist having a negative performance impact?

In the case of a full table refresh, it can often be faster to create a new instance of the view with a different name, then swap the names and drop the old instance. Seems silly when you have something like `concurrently` available but you're dealing exactly with a table and everything that comes along with a table including the finer points of MVCC and adjustments to support that.